# Magento 2 - Could not load content for ... (HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE)

Tags: magento2, grunt, livereload

I am using grunt with livereload to compile my less files. Grunt also generates source maps so that I can directly see in my browser, in which LESS files css code is located.

But often when I click to inspect it, then I get

`Could not load content for https://www.company.de/pub/static/frontend/company/fresh/de_DE/css/source/lib/extend/main/header/header_main.less (HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE)`

Why is this happening and how can I prevent it?

Comment: Did you find a fix? As an ugly hack I remove the `pub` from the URL to inspect in the browser. Are you using Valet?

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can replace `sourceMapRootpath: '/'` in [dev/tools/grunt/configs/less.js](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4.2/dev/tools/grunt/configs/less.js#L24) with `outputSourceFiles: true`.

REF:
https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-less/tree/v1.4.1#outputsourcefiles